# device info package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a small doubt. In this package, there is a function that returns a 'unique' id . This is the small code:

```
getDevice() async{


    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;

    var brand = androidInfo.id;

    setState(() {
          info = brand;

          });

}
```

it return me `PSR1.180720.093` as id. My doubt is, when I create another `virtual_device` (the same model with other name), and I execute the code, it returns `PSR1.180720.093`, the same. This code returns a real unique id? Why is it returning the same id in two different devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my guess, after reading this class:

```
https://pub.dev/documentation/device_info/latest/device_info/AndroidDeviceInfo-class.html
```

it seems that in order to get the android id unique that you want you should call:

```
androidInfo.androidId
```

[image]

It seems you are calling just id, not androidId. From the documentation:

id is:

Either a changelist number, or a label like "M4-rc20".

and androidId is:

The Android hardware device ID that is unique between the device + user and app signing.

So, to summerise, change androidInfo.id to androidIndo.androidId

Comment: You're right! i tested it and it's working, thank you